# Explanation on cdvfile:// protocol

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Currently working on Cordova App.

I use `<img class="profile-thumbnail" src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Photo/mypicture.jpg">`to display some content into the view.

When I generate a new `mypicture.jpg` using the file API to overwrite the existing one, then the picture disappear from the view and never come back before I kill and relaunch the app.

I try with:

```
$('.profile-thumbnail').attr('src','cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Photo/mypicture.jpg');
```

after my storage success call, but it still don't display the correct picture just after update.

When I relaunch the app, the new file is displayed properly.

So, how the cdvfile:// protocol handle updates?

Is there any cache to flush after updating the file?

Any preferred techniques to handle this kind of request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the way I store the updated picture was not correct.
I created the file, but the way I write my picture in it was wrong. So it displayed an empty file.